# I cant login due to new account GUEST

Tags: login

Now when my pc boots, there is another user named guest, and my PW for my account will not work. I put it in and it goes right back to the logon screen.

Answer (score 0):

The guest account is supposed to be there by default. And press "ctrl+alt+f1" all at a time to switch to tty1 and login with your user name and password. After logging into the tty1 shell, run `sudo chown -R your_username:your_username /home/your_username`, after a successful run, reboot your machine and see if it works.

Comment: Ill try that real quick

Comment: is there a way i can find my login name? everything i try says login incorrect

Comment: you are not sure about your user name?

Comment: nvm i logged on, whats the command to reboot?

Comment: try "sudo reboot"

Comment: I am still getting the login loop

Comment: Same loop, I put in my PW, brings me back to login screen

Comment: What did you do in your last successful login?

Comment: after using cntrl alt f1, it lets me login and use the terminal fine, i last logged in day before yesterday ***without any problems, is there a way to go back using a recovery system?

Comment: I played counterstrike global offensive, as i always do, this machine is primarily for gaming

Comment: Can you login to guest account?

Comment: No, i get the same loop when i try guest as well.

Comment: i still cant do anything at login

Comment: login to tty1 shell and type "startx", if it does not work then type "sudo startx" and see. Its a workaround.

Comment: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operating not Permitted) modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_352': Required key not available xinit: connection to X server lost

Comment: Thats what i get

Comment: try `sudo chown your_username:your_username /home/your_username/.Xauthority` and reboot and retry.

Comment: And you might find a solution here http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop, But careful to notice which process actually worked for you. Because I had the same issue and when no method worked for me or may be I didn't tried much. I took an exhaustive method, backed up my home folders using live env (also possible from tty shell), then created another admin user and removed my old user and re-created, but still had permission issues with /home/user, so ran `sudo chown -R user:user /home/user` and only restored the docs and meta files but not the settings, worked